# I teleported too high on my Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friends own a Minecraft server and I was playing around with commands when I teleported to y 100000000000000000000000000000000 just because I wanted to see how high maps could go. That was a big mistake. Now every time I go on the server I crash.

I don't have access to the server files and I don't have the owner's email or phone number or anything and I'm the only one that plays on the server. I know that one solution is to make a new Minecraft character but that would involve me to pay.

Is there some way I can delete my player information or change the location without access to the server files? I don't want to leave the server because I've been building a castle for 3 months now and I don't want to give up that easy.

Comment: FYI Minecraft maps are 256 blocks high.

Comment: @Dracs The max build height is 256 blocks, entities can have higher `Y` values.

Comment: I'm assuming you get kicked for flying, and not the server crashing? If that's the case you'll have a whole lot of kicks coming in, in between every kick you'll fall a couple meters, and after you finally land all should be over. If it is effectively the server who crashes(very well possible with such a huge number), then you are out of luck.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I'm wondering: How could one possibly benefit by teleporting that high?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yer, you're basically screwed :I. Even though you don't have contact to the owner maybe try and get a friend to go online and get them to teleport you to the ground or get them to contact the owner, as only he will be able to fix this.

Answer (score 5):

You can only modify your player data either in-game or by accessing server files.

So, if you really don't have any contacts of your "friends", you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

if it sais **"Illegal Stance"** then it will be impossible to enter the server. it is because you go so high, that minecraft forcefully shuts you down since you go out of rendering view, and you can't play. this happens in singleplayer worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Have a friend lend you an account you can use to join the server, then personally contact the owner and tell him your situation. He should be able to force your spawn location with a plugin to free your character from the abyss.

Answer (score 0):

Get a friend to have a macro that makes them say "/tp [your username] [their username]" in chat and spam it while you try to join.

Answer (score -1):

You're screwed, unless you can manage to get a friend to talk to the owner about deleting the relevant server-side *insertplayername*.dat file.

Comment: This is no different from the accepted answer. Besides, it's 'you're' as in the contraction for 'you are', not 'your'.